# Separating Firebase notification for UAT, SIT and Prod

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my application I am using **Firebase Notification** for push notification.

In my Android app I have three build configurations with three different bundle identifiers.

**com.mycompany.myappQA**

**com.mycompany.myappDev**

**com.mycompany.myapp**

Here my doubt is,

When I create Application in Firebase console do I need to create three different apps for all the three environments? Or Is it possible for me to create **one app** and handle **all the three** different app configurations / Apps.

Answer (score 2):

One namespace = one app. To add more namespaces, more apps needs to be added to the project.

If notifications are the main reason for your different namespaces (per environment) and if you're using topics, maybe it would be better to just suffix or prefix the topic name and have the same namespace for all environments and just adjust the subscribe/unsubscribe topic name accordingly.

Comment: We have done this (3 setup) because there is a requirement from client to install all the 3 app on same device.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it help you. It will help more people. :)